# primefaces form and exceptions, how to reset to old value

Tags: java, input, primefaces

I have a primefaces form with three input texts, three numbers, and a button to do an ajax submit. 
When the user enter the page it shows, for example,

```
[ 1 ] + [ 2 ] = [ 3 ]
```

where 1, 2 y 3 are the values of the inputs, from the backing bean.
The user enter 4, 5 and 6, and then press the button. The backing bean call a remote bean function, and the remote bean check if 4 + 5 is equal to 6.
If it's ok it returns true, if not false and, if some number is invalid for some reason, it throws an IllegalArgumentException.

The point is: in which way I can restore the old values in the page? I mean, if the remote bean throw an exception I show a message to the user but the form still contains the new values entered.
If don't want to insert validation logic in the backing bean (because I don't know what kind of validations the remote beans do), is there a standard way to tell primefaces "go back"?

Thank you

EDIT:

I'll try to explain better the situation, sorry if it's unclear (and sorry for my english).

I've a frontend in primefaces, it's a page like "orders", it has an header with a lot of data and a lot of lines. Lines are displayed in a table an the user can edit every single line. The basic validation is done in the frontend: if it's a number, if it can contain decimals, etc. When the user press "ok, store the changes", primefaces submit the values to the backing bean, the backing bean does other validations using remote bean methods (like "checkIfSomethingIsValid") and, if something it's invalid, it display a message using growl, etc.

I cannot check and validate every fields with remote bean, because every change will be an ajax call to the backing bean and then a remote method call, making the frontend impossible to use, mainly because the user input is generally faster.

In remote bean the final submit is done via other service (it can be via WS or via socket) and so the final submit can fail, and it can fail for various reasons, no only "it's ok" or "it's not ok", so I cannot return simply true or false because I must inform the user. In case, for example, the WS reply with "there's no such quantity" I generate an OutOfStockException.

The backing bean get the exception and show, with growl, a message to the user: "Sorry, we have no stock".

So, what's the point? The point is that when the user modify a line, pass all the basics validations and then submit it, in case of error he still see the modified line, but in I want to rollback to the old line.

- the user see the line "80 PKG / TOMATOES / 0% DISCOUNT / PRICE 10€"
- the user change the line to "90 PKG / TOMATOES / 10% DISCOUNT / PRICE 9€"
- the user submit the line
- the remote bean submit the line to the remote service
- the remote service says "we don't have 90 pkg"
- the remote bean throw OutOfStockException
- the backing bean manage the exception and send a message
- the frontend displays "Sorry, we're out of stock"
- the user must see the old line (with "80 PKG") because the remote submit fail, but it still see the edited line (with "90 PKG")

So, is there a way to tell primefaces "rollback the last submit"? Or I have to do all by hand, storing old values and then restoring it?

I hope I've explained it clearly now. 
Thank you!

Comment: throwing an exception for validation is not a good solution. Can you share some code ? markup of your inputs and you action method.

Comment: ok, change "validation" for "cannot save to database": your backend for some reason throw an exception and so you need to restore the old form values. I don't figure out how to do it.

Comment: if an uncatched exception is thrown by the servlet, it redirects a page which show an error is occurred.

Comment: I'm sorry, It's difficulto for me to explain this better in english. I try: I've a page with a lot of data, for example an order, with lot of lines. The user change the quantity of one line from "20 boxes" to "30 boxes" The backend does calculation and, converting between units, discover I've no stock, so throw a "NotInStockException". The frontend manage the exception and show a message: "Sorry, there's no stock". The line has to be reverted to "20 boxes" because 30 is incorrect.
Sorry if I failed explain, at least I've tried.
Thanks

Comment: I do not want to demotivate you. I can suggest to use Custom Validator in your case http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/ .p:growl or p:messages to show messages to users, instead of throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @erencan that you should use a custom validator to check that the result of all the fields is correct during JSF's validation phase. This will ensure that the user wont be able to insert a wrong value, sice it will fail duing validation, so there won't be any need to revert back to the old value manually.

If you want to use a different solution you could store the old value inside a hidden inputfield and revert to it if necessary. I think something like this should work:

XHTML:

```
        <p:growl id="growl" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" />
        <p:inputText value="#{playgroundController.fieldOne}"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{playgroundController.fieldTwo}"/>
        <p:inputText id="result" value="#{playgroundController.result}"/>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{playgroundController.hiddenResult}" id="hiddenResult" />

        <p:commandButton value="check result" actionListener="#{playgroundController.checkResult()}" update="growl result hiddenResult" />
```

Bean:

```
private int fieldOne;
private int fieldTwo;
private int result;
private int hiddenResult = 0;
//getters & setters 

public void checkResult() {

    if (fieldOne + fieldTwo == result) {
        addMessage("Result is correct");
        hiddenResult = result;
    } else {
        addMessage("Result is false");
        result = hiddenResult;
    }

}

private void addMessage(String message) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(message);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Comment: really thant you @emil kaminski, I've edited the question trying to explain better what I want to achieve.